# Scribble Pad for Nerds

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, array, binary-matrix

aka. implement an easier version of [05ab1e's canvas element](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/96361/tips-for-golfing-in-05ab1e/175520#175520).

## Description

The canvas element is used to draw ASCII lines on the screen.
The (easier version of the) canvas element takes a list of integers and returns a multi-line string (or a list of strings).
The integers map to the following directions:

```
7   0   1
  ↖ ↑ ↗
6 ← X → 2
  ↙ ↓ ↘
5   4   3

0: upwards
1: top-right
2: right
3: bottom-right
4: downwards
5: bottom-left
6: left
7: top-left
```

If given eg. `[6, 4, 2]`, it outputs this:

```
###
#
###
```

[image: Explanation Image]

1. Start with one hash already drawn (`X`)
2. Draw two hashes towards the left (direction `6`)
3. Draw two hashes downwards (direction `4`)
4. Draw two hashes towards the right (direction `2`)

## Rules

- [Default Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply
- Multiple integers or a list of integers will be given as the input
- Output must be a string, a list of strings, or a matrix of characters (like a binary matrix)
- You will not receive directions with intersecting lines
- You can replace `#` with any other constant character, but you'll always have to draw **2** hashes per direction and **start** with a hash
- Excess whitespace is allowed
- The shortest code, as this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), wins

## Examples

````
In: [1, 5, 3, 7, 5, 1, 7, 3]
Out:
#   #
 # # 
  #  
 # # 
#   #

In: [2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 7, 7]
Out:
#########
     #  #
      # #
       ##
        #

In: [1, 2, 3, 6, 6, 2, 4, 2, 2, 4, 2, 6, 4, 2, 1, 3, 2, 6, 7, 5, 6, 6, 4, 0, 6, 4, 0, 6, 0, 6, 2, 0, 2]
Out:
  ###            
 #   #           
# #####          
    #            
  #######        
  #     #        
###     ### #    
  #     #  # #   
  #########   ###
    # #          
    # #          

```
````

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/24800#24800)

Comment: How strict are the whitespace rules? Is trailing whitespace required, and is excess whitespace allowed?

Comment: Also you should consider adding an example that draws a cat.

Comment: @ConorO'Brien excess whitespace is allowed, I'll edit it

Comment: What's the winning criterion? The questions seems to be silent about it.

Comment: @TheFifthMarshal oh wow I forgot, [tag:code-golf]

Answer (score 13):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes

```
×3ø^
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLDlzPDuF4iLCIiLCJbMiwgMiwgMiwgMiwgNCwgNCwgNywgN10iXQ==)

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

```
3$Λ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fWOXc7P//o410FODIBIzMgSgWAA)

Comment: lol yeah I expected this one

Answer (score 11):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 9 bytes

```
ＦＡ✳ι##‖↘#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8tv0hBwzOvoLREQ1NTIaAoM69EwyWzKDW5JDM/TyNTU0dBSVlZSdOaKyg1LQcoqmHlkl@eF5SZnlECFISoVwIp@P8/OtpIRwGOTMDIHIhiY//rluUAAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
ＦＡ
```

Loop over the directions.

```
✳ι##
```

Print two `#`s in that direction.

```
‖↘
```

Reflect to switch from Charcoal to 05AB1E coordinates. This is because Charcoal's coordinate system has `0` as right and `2` as up etc.

```
#
```

Print the final `#`.

Boring built-in version:

```
ＧＨ✳✳⁻²Ａ³#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5///9nuXv96x4NGczCDXuPrTp/Z6FhzYr//8fHW2kowBHJmBkDkSxsQA) <s>Link is to verbose version of code</s> Unfortunately the version of Charcoal on TIO has a bug in its deverbosifier meaning that it parses `Directions()` as `Direction(s)`. I could use a capital `S`... or you could just [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iOSOxKDk_MWfBgqWlJWm6FjdNA_JzKtPz8zzyc3LyyzVcMotSk0sy8_OKNXwz80qLNYx0FDzzCkpLNDQ1NXUUjHUUlJSVNK2XFCclF0ONWB6tpFuWoxS7KzoaqBiOTMDIHIhiYyEKAQ) Link is to verbose version of code. Note that the `PolygonHollow` line drawing code takes the lengths of the lines rather than the number of additional `#`s to draw.

Answer (score 9):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>25</s>  22 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

<sup>Saved three bytes using the allowance of excess whitespace (this also fixed a bug that meant an input with only left and/or right movements would have printed incorrectly since no space or newline characters were being introduced in such cases).</sup>

```
ı2½*Nx2ŻÆiNṠ+\+L$ŒṬo⁶Y
```

A full program that accepts the list of instructions and prints the result using `1` as the character.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///IRqNDe7X8KoyO7j7clun3cOcC7RhtH5Wjkx7uXJP/qHFb5P///6MNdRRMdRSMdRTMwQxDMMM4FgA)**

#### How?

Jelly has no canvas drawing built-ins, so instead this builds a matrix of zeros and ones, with ones at visited locations and prints it with spaces in place of zeros joined with newline characters.

```
ı2½*Nx2ŻÆiNṠ+\+L$ŒṬo⁶Y - Main Link: list of integers from [0,7]:
ı2                     - 2i (twice the square root of -1)
  ½                    - square root
    N                  - negate the input (vectorises)
   *                   - exponentiate (vectorises)
     x2                - repeat each element twice
       Ż               - prefix with a zero
        Æi             - convert each to [real, imaginary] parts
          N            - negate (vectorises)
           Ṡ           - sign (vectorises)
             \         - cumulative reduce by:
            +          -   addition (vectorises)
                $      - last two links as a monad:
               L       -   length
              +        -   add (vectorises)
                 ŒṬ    - matrix with 1s at the indicated [row, column]s
                   o⁶  - logical OR with space character
                     Y - join with newline characters
                       - implicit, smashing print
```

Note: `ı2` is a hack - `ı` should work but there are floating-point errors - for example, `ı½*-2` gives `2.220446049250313e-16-1j` rather than `0-1j`.

Comment: woah that's big

Comment: @mathcat yep, hence why this kind of thing is built-in in so many golfing languages! Slightly shorter now due to the excess whitespace allowance though.

Comment: Heh, and I was thinking "Wow, for a language without a builtin, that's super short" ;)

Answer (score 9):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 106 bytes

```ruby
->d{m=2*x=y=d.size*2;c=[]
[-5,*d].map{|k|2.times{(c[y+=k==6?0:k%7<=>2]||=[0]*m)[x+=k<1?0:4<=>k]=1}};c-[p]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVFha4MwEP3eX3E4Bq1LJYlWYW26H5Llg9OUdWInrYU64293mmvEUnjkXu4l7@648/Wr6Q@iX@/zthTcv4lG5MHl@Kd9vs2EVFu53hA/V0GZVq0pDA/qY6kv7TKTzZsohIg/6HvxmuzEnitjhKTKL1fyNmg7NkjRIBRKsK7bZmtZqa7P9QGqs67rZpmuFgAVpON5rS@QjlWgBaMN6Bn34MWT2hiuoIPg5/d4gg6D93ny7r8X@pQv6gwEyCEjYwIRAa7IeGEENgRCAoklzJJw0rjVYguO/2YkdoTZZ5hBo9ip9JFQZ0WnFmIMFAN3JbBKZA0T1CKXQrAZsN7dg9oU9h65dpJJo4/@oQVzwyduHMRmBlT5E3C6yZZZHrokxb7UsIJAp9n3uLrM3DcNB5kNu@v/AQ) Returns a binary matrix (1 for `#`, 0 for  ). A semicolon replaced for a newline for readability's sake (and the same byte count). Produces a lot of leading/trailing spaces in each row (most of the time).

I'm sure there's some more bytes to be shaved but I can't currently see what they are.

### Direction to coordinate formula

I'm not sure if this is the shortest, but I imagine this approach is shorter than an approach by complex exponentiation. For a given direction \$k\$, we want to produce the delta directions \$dx\$ and \$dy\$ to "nudge" our central coordinate along. We can see that, through some formula manipulation, we can do just that:

\begin{array} {|c|c|}
\hline k & dx & dy & k<1 & 4\Leftrightarrow k& & k=6 & k\bmod7 & k\bmod7\Leftrightarrow2 \\
\hline 0 & 0 & -1 & T & 1 & \mathbf{0} & F & 0 & -1 & \mathbf{-1} \\
\hline 1 & 1 & -1 & F & 1 & \mathbf{1} & F & 1 & -1 & \mathbf{-1} \\
\hline 2 & 1 & 0 & F & 1 & \mathbf{1} & F & 2 & 0 & \mathbf{0} \\
\hline 3 & 1 & 1 & F & 1 & \mathbf{1} & F & 3 & 1 & \mathbf{1} \\
\hline 4 & 0 & 1 & F & 0 & \mathbf{0} & F & 4 & 1 & \mathbf{1} \\
\hline 5 & -1 & 1 & F & -1 & \mathbf{-1} & F & 5 & 1 & \mathbf{1} \\
\hline 6 & -1 & 0 & F & -1 & \mathbf{-1} & T & 6 & 1 & \mathbf{0} \\
\hline 7 & -1 & -1 & F & -1 & \mathbf{-1} & F & 0 & -1 & \mathbf{-1} \\
\hline -5 &  &  & T & 1 & \mathbf{0} & F & 2 & 0 & \mathbf{0} \\
\hline \end{array}

Bolded cells above indicate taking the previous expression, but instead choosing zero if the previous condition holds. In code, we update our coordinates as thus:

```ruby
x += k < 1  ? 0 : 4 <=> k
y += k == 6 ? 0 : k % 7 <=> 2
```

Important to note is that \$-5\$, as well as any other number \$c<1\$ for which \$c\equiv 2\mod 7\$, produces a 0 in both coordinates, and is useful as a placeholder to mean "no action", and hence a useful initialization instruction.

### Commented code

```ruby
-> d {
  # x and y are initially set to d.size * 2, guaranteeing us sufficient room
  # so that our calculations will not step outside of bounds.
  # m is our minimum width for padding purposes for such a bound, and extends
  # the distance from 0 to x or y in each direction, that is, 2x or 2y
  m = 2 * x = y = d.size * 2
  c = []
  # to account for the initial cell, we prepend -5 to the input (see above table)
  [-5, *d].map { |k|
    # since each line is two characters long, we update each cell individually
    2.times {
      # update y, as per above
      y += k == 6 ? 0 : k % 7 <=> 2
      # get the current row, defaulting to an appropriate row of 0s
      row = c[y] ||= [0] * m
      # update x, as per above
      x += k < 1 ? 0 : 4 <=> k
      # update (x,y) in the output array
      row[x] = 1
    }
  }
  # remove all nil rows from the output array
  c - [p]
}
```

Comment: Is something wrong with the submission, @downvoter? or were there too many numbers in this post :P

Comment: @downvoter  ̷I̷'̷m̷ ̷p̷e̷r̷s̷o̷n̷a̷l̷l̷y̷ ̷o̷f̷f̷e̷n̷d̷e̷d̷ ̷b̷y̷ ̷t̷h̷i̷s̷

Answer (score 7):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), <s>79</s> <s>77</s> <s>71</s> <s>67</s> <s>58</s> <s>53</s> 51 bytes

*Saved 5 bytes thanks to [att](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/81203/att)*

```
' '+(¬⊸-↑↑⟜1)∘⋈˜∘¬⟜-∘≠{(∨⌽)´-}4(⊢×○×-)2/8|-⟜2⊸⋈¨
```

[Try it at BQN online](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAgJyAnKyjCrOKKuC3ihpHihpHin5wxKeKImOKLiMuc4oiYwqzin5wt4oiY4omge/Cdlago8J2VqOKIqOKMvSnCtC3wnZWpfTQo4oqiw5fil4vDly0pMi84fC3in5wy4oq44ouIwqgKCkYgMeKAvzXigL8z4oC/N+KAvzXigL8x4oC/N+KAvzM=)

#### Explanation

New approach!

```
8|-⟜2⊸⋈¨
```

Turn each number in the initial list of directions into a list containing two numbers, the first number shifted two directions counterclockwise (i.e. minus 2, mod 8). These will become the y and x deltas, respectively.

```
2/
```

Repeat each direction twice.

```
4(⊢×○×-)
```

Turn the directions into deltas. We want to implement the following function:

- 0 or 4 -> 0
- 1, 2, or 3 -> 1
- 5, 6, or 7 -> -1

We almost get the desired result if we subtract the input from 4 and take the sign. The only problem is that 0 becomes 1, which we can fix by multiplying by the sign of the input: `sign(4-x) * sign(x)`, in C-like pseudocode. In BQN, `×○×` is a dyadic function that takes the sign of each argument and multiplies them; `(⊢×○×-)` is a dyadic train that passes its right argument and the difference of its arguments to `×○×`; and so if we give it `4` as its left argument and a direction number as its right argument, it will return the desired delta. Since all of the functions used here are pervasive, we can apply them to a list of lists of numbers and get a list of lists of results.

```
(¬⊸-↑↑⟜1)∘⋈˜∘¬⟜-∘≠
```

Call the length of the original list \$N\$. (The length of the list of deltas is \$2N\$ because we repeated each move twice.) Construct a \$4N+1\$ by \$4N+1\$ array that is filled with 0s but with a 1 in the exact center.

```
{(∨⌽)´-}
```

Negate each delta and right-fold the list of deltas using the following procedure: Start with the \$4N+1\$ array constructed above. At each step, rotate the partial result by the current delta, and then logical OR with another copy of the \$4N+1\$ array. The result is a \$4N+1\$ by \$4N+1\$ array of 0s and 1s.

```
' '+
```

Add a space character, converting the 0s to spaces and the 1s to `!`s.

Comment: I noticed you 1 byte shorter than mine originally and fought for the reduction I got... I'm not sure I can get under 67 though, but I'll make it my mission to try :P

Comment: you can remove the `⊸` in `' '⊸+`

Comment: @DomHastings I see you got under 67. However, I just found a new approach and got down to 58... ;)

Comment: can shorten the initial array generation further with `(¬⊸-↑↑⟜1)∘≍˜∘¬⟜-∘≠`

Comment: @att Oh, that's *clever*!

Comment: Oof. And 53 now. I'm not sure I can get there, but I'll try!

Comment: another [-2 bytes](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAgJyAnK+KGleKImMKs4p+cLeKKuD3iiJgry5ziiJjiiaDiiKfijJzLnOKKuHvwnZWoKPCdlajiiKjijL0pwrQt8J2VqX00KOKKosOX4peLw5ctKTIvOHwt4p+cMuKKuOKLiMKoCgpGIDHigL814oC/M+KAvzfigL814oC/MeKAvzfigL8z)

Comment: right side can be `2/2×∘-|∘-⟜4‿2¨`

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-pl043F`, 63 bytes

```perl
$_=". "x@F.s/./(<#{DA,A,,B,BD,{B,,A}DD}>)[$&]x2/ger;s/\w/.[$&/g
```

[Try it online!](https://dom111.github.io/code-sandbox/#eyJsYW5nIjoid2VicGVybC01LjI4LjEiLCJjb2RlIjoiJF89XCJcZiBcInhARi5zLy4vKDwje0RBLEEsLEIsQkQse0IsLEF9RER9PilbJCZdeDIvZ2VyO3MvXFx3L1x1MDAxYlskJi9nIiwiYXJncyI6Ii1wbDA0M0YiLCJpbnB1dCI6IjY0MiJ9)

### Explanation

The solution utilises ANSI escape sequences to move the cursor to the required position based on the input commands. First `$_` is reset to `@F` (a list containing each character of the input, which, when interpreted as a scalar, returns the length of the list) repetitions of `\f`  (form-feed followed by space) to move the cursor to a position to allow enough space for the output (hopefully...), concatenated with the original input `s///`ubstituting each digit (`.`) with its index into the `glob` list (`<#{DA,A,,B,BD,{B,,A}DD}>`). This results in a string like: `#A#A#BDD#BDD#B#B#DDA#DDA#BDD#BDD#A#A#DDA#DDA#B#B#` where the letters correspond to the ANSI escape sequence to move either left, up or down. These letters are then replaced with the correct ANSI escape sequences in the final `s///`ubstitution.

[Bonus "cat" drawing.](https://dom111.github.io/code-sandbox/#eyJsYW5nIjoid2VicGVybC01LjI4LjEiLCJjb2RlIjoiJF89XCJcZiBcInhARi5zLy4vKDwje0RBLEEsLEIsQkQse0IsLEF9RER9PilbJCZdeDIvZ2VyO3MvXFx3L1x1MDAxYlskJi9nIiwiYXJncyI6Ii1wRi8uLi4uLi4uLyIsImlucHV0IjoiMjIyMzIyMjIyMjEyMjI2NjYxMjIyNjY2MDA3Njc3NDQ2Njc3NDQ2NTQ0NjY2MjIyMzczNzIyMjIyMjIyMjI2NjY2NDY2MDY3MTM1MjIyMjcxMzUifQ==)

Comment: Ooh nice, Perl!

Comment: @mathcat Bonus cat: [Try it online!](https://dom111.github.io/code-sandbox/#eyJsYW5nIjoid2VicGVybC01LjI4LjEiLCJjb2RlIjoiJF89XCJcZiBcInhARi5zLy4vKCRcXC4oMTAsMCxcIlwiLDIsMjEsMjExLDExLDExMClbJCZdKXgyL2dlcjtzL1xcZC9cIlx1MDAxYltcIi4oQSxELEIpWyQmXS9nZSIsImZvb3RlciI6IjskXFw9QSIsImFyZ3MiOiItcGwwNDNGLyguezExfSkvIiwiaW5wdXQiOiIyMjIzMjIyMjIyMTIyMjY2NjEyMjI2NjYwMDc2MDA1NTY2Nzc0NDY1NDQ2NjYyMjIzNzM3MjIyMjIyMjIyMjY2NjY1NzY3MTM1MjIyMjcxMzUifQ==) Maybe it looks a little more like an owl...

Comment: wow, looks nice!

Answer (score 1):

## [C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)) ([gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/)): <s>218</s> 210 bytes

**Edit**: Thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat) for shortening the code to *210 bytes*.

```c
p=297,C[800]={[297]=3},d,j=800;f(D,n){d^D?:(C[p+=n]=C[p+=n]=3);}main(c,v)char**v;{for(;d=*v[--c]-48,c;f(0,-40))f(7,-41),f(6,-1),f(5,39),f(4,40),f(3,41),f(2,1),f(1,-39);for(;j--;j%40?:puts(""))putchar(C[j]+32);}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##dVPfb5swEH7nrzh1moAWKAH6E6FqSl76Vml7izLJsU1wFmyEDair@q@Xnc1aVZMWgs9wd999952h8YHSefYuL@FHQ@QvDUYB5eIk5IESA7XqQTeqN1ziGzANB6oYt1HZKoX9s@Has9n@enubpjsfhHZR2QYokSPREKArS3fbAr0h1CdiEIwzUIOxMKsNEMkQVRoipEu2eKquNTdoHNq37@vHR6AN6Qk1vF841L1qIc8g4MkhAf@L/28AUsmvLNgeS01qODHYc9BG9VgemeVhgl1jFP73nJJBY44URpCT@G3bJRJI35NnmIRp8OnZMUNCPYzkNKAMqBmkNl8qg@U56SDQHaE8noTmoWtNSIzDEEosvvFtMWNJGmXxjoM2QBizrUwNSjOiS3LOOEucsp1vR2DZd0pIJ5rVpBWMnfi7Qu9it@LQGNvm1Cvs4P4pTLyuyu5uomVA1csWH3ZV/hqx6Fjhq3IZPhJs1ciX6dGh1zh5y571ZNKQWX310gpK2HEqaoEqMtFzaoSS4G/8xKuDTSTDF/Zz83AfrLfdRSV31bvNw/LVa3HIAY3G0M7q/HwsXzz4@0MaayWxe4Naqba11fEccpzBYWi5NO5wouA@quB/IqfkJwmSDzw8u0HJqvNxG8d0Fxe3ES3rII3iIg3DOrjBzSqM6uA6ip29ivI7a4sIA9Dm0eLPImdWUYz@8jPdp97N43@1j3FcHr8W6cN9NxgdnJ2FIW5s46jNcXeRZwj36s3zvJqzOZ@v8crmAu9lvXbrCj12fzNfuYhiTj/W1GWkc/ZG8cM66Dme/gA) (with explanation)

**Explanation**:

```c
// Thanks to ceilingcat for shortening the code to 210 bytes

// 'C[800]' is the 2D canvas ('C[20][40]') flattened out to 1D and contains the
// offset of the ASCII character code from 32 (e.g. '#' character code is 35
// but would be stored as 3). This is because initializing an array with any
// other value than 0 is not cheap (space-wise) and in this case it's better to
// just add 32 whenever needed.
// 'p' should point to the middle of the canvas (might be wrong :P).
p=297,C[800]={[297]=3},d,j=800;
// This moves the cursor and draws 2 '#'s in the specified direction 'D'.
f(D,n){d^D?:(C[p+=n]=C[p+=n]=3);}
main(c,v)char**v;{
        // Converts command line arguments to an 'int' and draws on the canvas.
        for(;d=*v[--c]-48,c;f(0,-40))f(7,-41),f(6,-1),f(5,39),f(4,40),f(3,41),f(2,1),f(1,-39);
        // Print the canvas.
        for(;j--;j%40?:puts(""))putchar(C[j]+32);
}
```

Comment: nice, C!~~~~~~~

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 125 bytes

```python
from turtle import*
mode("logo")
def f(l,w=write):
 reset();ht();pu();w("#")
 for d in l:seth(d*45);fd(9);w("#");fd(9);w("#")
```

Comment: Hmm yeah okay I'll let this count :P

Comment: @mathcat Was quite surprised nobody had already done this! :D

Comment: What's the point of a TIO link if it doesn't have the module installed?

Comment: @Neil None what so ever, removed.